# Load image from Foursquare URL to UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, uiimageview, foursquare

I have a table view where I list the nearest venues with the Foursquare API. All fine but now I want to add the category icon. I can get the URL of that image but how to display it on a UIImageView?

I tried open that URL from chrome but wasn't possible "https://ss1.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/coffeeshop.png"

```
{
    icon =     {
        prefix = "https://ss1.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/coffeeshop_";
        suffix = ".png";
    };
    id = 4bf58dd8d48988d1e0931735;
    name = "Coffee Shop";
    pluralName = "Coffee Shops";
    primary = 1;
    shortName = "Coffee Shop";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append size to suffix in response from available sizes like `64`.Refer more from `fourSquare` [docs](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/category) .You need to add size with sufix

> Combine prefix with a size (32, 44, 64, and 88 are available)

https://ss1.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/coffeeshop_64.png

You can use

```
NSString *imgUrl =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", response[@"icon"][@"prefix"],@"64",response[@"icon"][@"suffix"]]
```

add `64` as it repersents size 64*64

If you want to set on `imageview` than use

```
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: imgUrl]];
UIImageView *yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData: imageData]];
```

This is synchrounous so it will block `main thread` use other asynchrounous options

Comment: Thank you very much @codester !! it's working now. The only problem as you said is that's working in the main thread. Can you tell me where check about asynchrounous options?

Comment: Use SDWebImageCahe library for loading the images.It is best for lazy loading of images.It is very good library https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage